# How to emulate a browser HTTPS POST request with Java (Apache HTTP Client)?

Tags: java, http, https, web-crawler

There is a website with an AJAX API. I have opened Firebug to look into the details of the login HTTPS POST request.

Then I have tried to do the same POST request from my Java program using Apache HTTP Client. But somehow the server identified my request as a non browser request. It sends a security exception message, which tells me that.

When all request headers are the same, what else could identify my client as not a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's a cookie issue (e.g. JSESSIONID the browser has stored). Include the session information with your POST. Have a look at the cookies of this site. Try disabling cookies for this site a have a look a the request again.

Answer (score 1):

`user-agent` header? ["httpclient.useragent" property](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/package-summary.html)

[Use debug mode](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html) to see full wire logging and compare the request with firebug's one.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know about the POST request but there is this for a multipart request

> MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

see if its of any help

**EDIT**: Code sample for a multipart request

> String createOrderUrl = Constants.CREATE_ORDER_URL;

```
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(createOrderUrl);

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            // add the information to the multipart request
            entity.addPart("msisdn", new StringBody("something"));
            entity.addPart("recipientname", new StringBody("something"));
            entity.addPart("recipientnumber", new StringBody("something"));
            entity.addPart("recipientaddress", new StringBody("something"));

            // add the images
            for (String imagePath : selectedImages)
            {
                FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(imagePath));

                entity.addPart("image", bin);

            }
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            return httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Thank you for this hint. But how to fill the MultipartEntity with my key-value pairs?